# Select to autocomplete angular directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, autocomplete

I am looking for a way to make my select into an autocomplete field. I know of angularJS directives that give you autocomplete functionality, but these don't allow the input name (what the user sees) and the input value (what the system uses) to be different. I need a select box, however, because the option name (that the user will see) and the option value (that the system will use) are different.

I know of such a plugin for jQuery, [selectToAutocomplete](https://github.com/JamieAppleseed/selectToAutocomplete), which is pretty neat and works well, but I would prefer to stay with AngularJS as much as possible. Is there an AngularJS alternative for jQuery selectToAutocomplete?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Angular UI ( http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ ) has a directive Typeahead which should fit your requirements. Look at that page for the 3rd example under **Typeahead** section with title **Custom templates for results**

Comment: Wow, this did actually work. I didn't expect it to be that easy. :) Thanks!